# setInterval() for a canvas drawing not giving smooth animation?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I was trying to make a clock using canvas. I tried to animate it myself by putting a setInterval timer on the `drawClock()` function so that every second, the time gets updated to the clock will reappear with the new time. But it seems like maybe the clock is being drawn elsewhere every time the function is called again, as the needles are giving unexpected results.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height/2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.90;
setInterval(drawClock,1000);
function drawClock() {
 drawFace();
 drawNumbers();
 drawTime();
}
function drawFace() {
 ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*3.14);
 ctx.fillStyle = "white";
 ctx.fill();
}
function drawNumbers() {
 ctx.font = radius*0.15 + "px arial";
 ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
 ctx.textAlign = "center";
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 for(var i = 1 ; i < 13 ; i++) {
  var angle = i * Math.PI / 6;
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.translate(0, -0.85 * radius);
  ctx.rotate(-angle);
  ctx.fillText(i.toString(), 0, 0);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.translate(0, 0.85*radius);
  ctx.rotate(-angle);
 }
}
function drawTime() {
 var now = new Date();
 var hours = now.getHours();
 hours %= 12;
 var minutes = now.getMinutes();
 var seconds = now.getSeconds();
 hours = hours + minutes/60 + seconds/360;
 minutes = minutes + seconds/60;
 var sAngle = seconds * 2*Math.PI / 60;
 var mAngle = minutes * 2*Math.PI / 60;
 var hAngle = hours * 2*Math.PI / 12;
 drawNeedles(10, hAngle, 0.4 * radius);
 drawNeedles(10, mAngle, 0.7 * radius);
 drawNeedles(2, sAngle, 0.7 * radius);
}
function drawNeedles(width, angle, length) {
 ctx.lineWidth = width;
 ctx.moveTo(0,0);
 ctx.rotate(angle);
 ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.rotate(-angle);
}
```

```css
#canvas {
 background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
    <body>
     <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `beginPath()` and `clearRect()`every iteration.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height/2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.90;
setInterval(drawClock,1000);
function drawClock() {
    ctx.clearRect(-radius,-radius,canvas.width,canvas.height)
 drawFace();
 drawNumbers();
 drawTime();
}
function drawFace() {
    ctx.beginPath(); // Added by Blindman67
 ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*3.14);
 ctx.fillStyle = "white";
 ctx.fill();
}
function drawNumbers() {
 ctx.font = radius*0.15 + "px arial";
 ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
 ctx.textAlign = "center";
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 for(var i = 1 ; i < 13 ; i++) {
  var angle = i * Math.PI / 6;
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.translate(0, -0.85 * radius);
  ctx.rotate(-angle);
  ctx.fillText(i.toString(), 0, 0);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.translate(0, 0.85*radius);
  ctx.rotate(-angle);
 }
}
function drawTime() {
 var now = new Date();
 var hours = now.getHours();
 hours %= 12;
 var minutes = now.getMinutes();
 var seconds = now.getSeconds();
 hours = hours + minutes/60 + seconds/360;
 minutes = minutes + seconds/60;
 var sAngle = seconds * Math.PI / 60;
 var mAngle = minutes * Math.PI / 60;
 var hAngle = hours * Math.PI / 12;
 drawNeedles(10, hAngle, 0.4 * radius);
 drawNeedles(10, mAngle, 0.7 * radius);
 drawNeedles(2, sAngle, 0.7 * radius);
}
function drawNeedles(width, angle, length) {
    ctx.beginPath(); // Added by Blindman67
 ctx.lineWidth = width;
 ctx.moveTo(0,0);
 ctx.rotate(angle);
 ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.rotate(-angle);
}
```

```css
#canvas {
 background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
    <body>
     <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do we need to beginPath(), each time we try to make something new ,like a new shape ?

Comment: You did not make the required changes to the example code. Add `ctx.beginPath()` at the first line of the function `drawNeedles`and `drawFace`